# Postfix not send emails to remote MX Record (same domain in localhost)

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, g-suite, gmail

I have a domain with mydomain.com configured in a postfix server, these domain have configured MX records to Google Suite

In the postfix server i have the user:

> user1@mydomain.com

In Google Suite I have the user:

> user2@mydomain.com

The MX record setup to mydomain.com

> aspmx.l.google.com

When I send a mail from "user1@mydomain.com" to => "user2@mydomain.com" postfix believes that it should deliver mail locally and does not do so to the remote server at Google.

> user2@mydomain.com: user unknown
>
> Jun  4 04:08:47 correos postfix/pipe[45963]: 388E3D3F723: to=, relay=dovecot, delay=0.04, delays=0.01/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)

Here no apear's logs to Google Suite

user1@mydomain.com also needs to receive emails (which with a rule from Google Suite redirect to my postfix server)

How can I force emails to be sent to the remote MX server?

Thank you.

```
# Global Postfix configuration file. This file lists only a subset
# of all parameters. For the syntax, and for a complete parameter
# list, see the postconf(5) manual page (command: "man 5 postconf").
#
# For common configuration examples, see BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README
# and STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README. To find these documents, use
# the command "postconf html_directory readme_directory", or go to
# http://www.postfix.org/.
#
# For best results, change no more than 2-3 parameters at a time,
# and test if Postfix still works after every change.



queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_protocols = all
#mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES


myhostname = mails.mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains = 
#
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf

virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf

virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
#
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_tls_security_level = may

smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept

tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I believe you need to use `transport_maps`. Add a line to `/etc/postfix/transport` with `user2@mydomain.com smtp:<GOOGLE_SERVER>:<SMTP_PORT>. More info: http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Comment: @Bangaio Hello, I must do this in a general way, I CANNOT be adding each new user in my mail service for this, I have more than 5000 accounts.